# Is it possible to map a custom domain (Via C Name or A Record) to an azure event hub

Tags: azure, dns, servicebus, azure-eventhub

Would it be possible to map a url to point to an instance of the azure event hub?

Could I add a CNAME to a domain and point to sb://.servicebus.windows.net

I think that A Records map to a static IP address, and as there doesn't seem to be an option to configure that in Azure I don't think that would work, but would it be possible so that all requests to something like https://serivcebus.mydomain.com could be pushed to the event hub?

We have a requirement to embed the connection to the event hub into our SDK which will be pushed out to a huge volume of customer devices, which may or may not be upgraded if we change. In order to support us potentially changing the technology behind the end point being posted to we wanted to map it to our own domain, allowing us, if needed, to swap out the back end technology without changing the code on clients devices.

There is potential to do this via our own Gateway API but then that may bottleneck the benefits gained from using the service bus itself.

Comment: Have you tried with the CNAME (it should work)?

Comment: Did the CNAME work?

Comment: We ended up putting a web gateway infront of the event hub and it basically just passed the messages through. The CName obviously worked fine on that.

Comment: Would be nice if MS would comment on this. Seems like a major design oversight to have to put an API Gateway in front of the Service Bus just to use a custom DNS name when the Service Bus endpoint is designed to handle copious amounts of direct traffic.

Comment: I tried using the CNAME, but I can't get the connection. When I observe the network messages tab, there are no messges being send when I use the CNAME. As I understand, the server should return a "101 switching protocols" response, which is not happening with my CNAME. Any ideas? I agree that using an API gateway defeats the purpose, @James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up putting a web app infront of the event hub and it basically just passed the messages through. The CName obviously worked fine on that.